# Correct "ROS" way to deal with different namespaces for nodes/topics

Tags: ros, navigation, namespaces

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The ros2-controlles package has a DiffDriveController node that listens to the Twist messages on ["~/cmd_vel"](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_controllers/blob/master/diff_drive_controller/src/diff_drive_controller.cpp#L33)

I followed the bring up demo [repo](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros2_control_demos/blob/master/ros2_control_demo_bringup/launch/diffbot_system.launch.py) and created my own launch file, after removing the rviz related part.

When I listed the topics I saw that the cmd_vel took the namespace of the controller node as in:

```
/diff_drive_controller/cmd_vel
```

Another package that publishes to the "cmd_vel" topic is the [telepop-joy](https://github.com/ros2/teleop_twist_joy) which lets you publish to cmd_vel using a PS3/PS4 joytstick.

That node publishes to "/cmd_vel" in the global namespace.

One approach I had is to remap the namespace while launching the joystick node, which had some success, but there is some quirk where the joystick output is constant, i.e only a single value is given no matter how much I move the stick.

My full launch file is [here](https://github.com/aboarya/ArMuMower/blob/main/armurenmower/launch/armurenmower_system.launch.py)

I am curious, what is the correct way to deal with this type of thing, where two packages work great on their own, but have different namespaces.  There has to be a "ros" way for this I imagine.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/383131/correct-%22ros%22-way-to-deal-with-different-namespaces-for-nodes/topics/) by [sameh4](https://answers.ros.org/users/76665/sameh4/) on ROS Answers with karma: 89 on 2021-07-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are already doing it correctly. I am using remapping in large projects, and they work great. The issues you have is probably caused by something else and not remapping or controller.

---

Originally posted by [destogl](https://answers.ros.org/users/4469/destogl/) with karma: 877 on 2022-03-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0